# Azure B2C - Automatically click "Send Verification Code" during Email OTP Validation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can we automatically send verification code during Email OTP?

Something similar to PhoneFactor?

```xml
  <Item Key="setting.autodial">true</Item>
```

Also possible to click on Continue button once the verification is complete? (without JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe either can be done without JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks mate.. Not good at JS.. if you have something working that would be awesome..